# Left outer Join query optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not so advanced sql user.
Could you please review my following query is it optimal ? or I can do something more more optimized and more readable?

```
      select  Distinct  DT.Station  , DT.Slot , DT.SubSlot, DT.CompID , CL.CompName
            from    (
                        select  Station, Slot, SubSlot, CompID
                        from    DeTrace
                        where   DeviceID = '1151579773'     
                    ) as DT 
            Left outer CList as CL  
                  on  DT.CompID = CL.CompID 
                  where CL.CompName = '9234220'
                  order by CompName
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to read like this:

```
 select  Distinct  DT.Station  , DT.Slot , DT.SubSlot, DT.CompID , CL.CompName
            from  DeTrace DT    
            Left outer join CList as CL  
                  on  DT.CompID = CL.CompID 
                  where CL.CompName = '9234220'
                    and DT.DeviceID = '1151579773'
                  order by CompName
```

The optimiser should be able to perform this query as efficiently as yours, but you should check the query execution plan just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DT.Station  , DT.Slot , DT.SubSlot, DT.CompID , CL.CompName
FROM DeTrace DT
LEFT OUTER JOIN CList CL ON DT.CompID = CL.CompID
                       AND DT.DeviceID = '1151579773'
                       AND CL.CompName = '9234220'
ORDER BY CL.CompName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need subquery. Check below:

```
select  Distinct  DT.Station  , DT.Slot , DT.SubSlot, DT.CompID , CL.CompName            
from    DeTrace as DT 
Left outer CList as CL  
on  DT.CompID = CL.CompID 
where CL.CompName = '9234220' and DeviceID = '1151579773'     
            order by CompName
```

Comment: If you use a WHERE clause in a join, it first joins ALL the records and then filter the result.  If you have the condition IN the join, then it first filters before joining all the records

Comment: I agree with you. But it may not return expected output and hence it's always advisable to put search predicate in where clause when using Outer Join as shown [here](http://nilthakkar.blogspot.in/2011/07/outer-joins-and-search-predicates.html)

Answer (score 0):

I like this way best:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        DeTrace.Station,
        DeTrace.Slot,
        DeTrace.SubSlot,
        DeTrace.CompID,
        CL.CompName
    FROM
        DeTrace
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        CList AS CL ON
            DeTrace.CompID = CL.CompID
    WHERE
        DeviceID = '1151579773' AND
        CL.CompName = '9234220'
    ORDER BY
        CL.CompName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  Distinct  DT.Station  , DT.Slot , DT.SubSlot, DT.CompID , CL.CompName                  
from    DeTrace DT
Left outer join CList as CL  
          on  DT.CompID = CL.CompID 
where DT.DeviceID = '1151579773' 
and  CL.CompName = '9234220'    
order by CL.CompName
```

The Sql Server Cost Based Optimizer should be able to determine the most efficient order in which to apply the conditions.